# R: Using sapply or str_replace_all instead of FindReplace

Tags: r, replace

Sample dataframe:

```
words <- c('Nothing', 'no thing', 'nada', 'nuthin', 'not a thing', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'Nothing', 'nil')
number <- c(1:9)
df <- data.frame(words, number)
```

In this df, I need to replace all the words that are equivalent to "nothing" with "Nothing". In this sample df, that is all the words but in reality the df has many words that should not be changed. I have a text file with the list of words that should be changed and I read that file in using read_delim. After reading the file in, 'changes' is shown as 'list' after running it through typeof() and as a  "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame" after running it through class().

I could only get FindReplace from the DataCombine package to work for me. I first created a replacement column in 'changes' then ran it through FindReplace.

```
changes <- mutate(changes, Replacement='Nothing')
df <- FindReplace(df, 'words', changes, from='words', to='Replacement', exact=TRUE, vector=FALSE)
```

The results are what I want.

```
words    number
Nothing  1
Nothing  2
Nothing  3
Nothing  4
Nothing  5
Nothing  6
Nothing  7
Nothing  8
Nothing  9
```

But I think there should be a way to run a loop over 'changes' and use sapply or str_replace_all to do this. But I could not get either of those to work. I kept getting the error: Error in UseMethod("type") : no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')". I would like to know how to get those two options to work if possible. Also, your thoughts on the DataCombine package would be appreciated. I haven't run across it before.

Comment: Can you share data from your actual `df` and show expected output for it? Also do you want answer from `DataCombine` package only or are open to other solutions?

Comment: @RonakShah, it is the 515k hotel reviews available from Kaggle, with over 515k rows and 17 columns. But I feel like the sample df I provided sufficiently represents what I am looking for. The number column isn't necessary, but reinforces the fact that my original is a dataframe and not a vector or list. I updated the question to show the results, which are fine, I got using DataCombine. I don't need help with that. I am hoping to get other options, from sapply and str_replace_all, but other options (I like dplyr) are great too. Also, if anyone uses DataCombine and what their thought on it are.

Answer (score 0):

the two ways that i do this is either with nested ifelse statements or a table of replacements and then left_join().

example nested ifelse:  you can loop this as many times as is needed.

```
    df %>%
       mutate(col_with_text = ifelse(col_with_text == "Nothing", "None",
                                    ifelse(col_with_text == "nada", "None", NA))
```

example of table and left join:

```
table_for_join <- data.frame(col_with_names = c('Nothing', 'no thing', 'nada', 'nuthin', 'not a thing', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'Nothing', 'nil'),
                             new_values = "None") # just made this one all the same for simplicity, but you can define this table however makes sense 

df %>%
  mutate(new_col = left_join(., table_for_join))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(words = str_replace_all(words, regex(" "), "")) %>% 
  mutate(words =  str_to_title(words, locale = "en")) %>% 
  mutate(words =  str_replace_all(words, regex("^Na.*|^Nu.*|^Nil.*|^Nota.*"), "Nothing"))
df2
#     words   number
# 1 Nothing      1
# 2 Nothing      2
# 3 Nothing      3
# 4 Nothing      4
# 5 Nothing      5
# 6 Nothing      6
# 7 Nothing      7
# 8 Nothing      8
# 9 Nothing      9
```